# Getting the error `f"The conn_id `{conn_id}` isn't defined` one of dag in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Getting error `f"The conn_id '{conn_id}' isn't defined` as one of dag which are using ec2 connection. but other dags are running using the same connection.

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/Java-Cron-Prod_Send_Trade_Order_Status_Daily.py] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base.py", line 68, in get_connection
    conn = Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(conn_id)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 410, in get_connection_from_secrets
    raise AirflowNotFoundException(f"The conn_id `{conn_id}` isn't defined")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `java-cron` isn't defined
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked for "The conn_id `java-cron` isn't defined" <- this? Is "java-cron" defined? Where is it defined? In which scope is it defined?

Comment: java-cron is a connection string, which is defined under Admin->connections.
and java-cron is the connection between airflow to the ec2 instance.
the dag is based on the SSHOperator.

Comment: It might be helpful to include the DAG code (with any sensitive info removed). It's also probably worthwhile confirming that the Connection indeed exists and that it's spelled correctly. What version of Airflow are you running?